# float numbers in c [Xcode IDE]

Tags: xcode, floating-point, numbers, double

I have started to learn c language but the problem is that I'm confused about how to use float numbers. I am using Xcode as IDE. Here are the results that got me confused:

```
float x1 = 1.123456789123456789f;  
double x2 = 1.123456789123456789f;  
float x3 = 987654321.123456789f;  
double x4 = 987654321.123456789f;  

printf("x1 = %.20f\n", x1);  
printf("x2 = %.20f\n", x2);  
printf("x3 = %10.10f\n", x3);  
printf("x4 = %10.10f\n", x4);
```

The output is:

```
x1 = 1.12345683574676513672  
x2 = 1.12345683574676513672  
x3 = 987654336.0000000000  
x4 = 987654336.0000000000
```

The question is, why `x1`, `x2` lose their float digits after `1.12345678`? And why `x3` and `x4` are truncated?

Comment: Also, x3 and x4 produces wrong decimal numbers - 987654336 instead of 987654321

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem here is that [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) only have a limited precision: they can only represent that many significant digits before they run out of space. It does **not** matter if those digits are before the decimal point or after it, the total number of significant digits matters. Note that this issue is **not** restricted to C, it can be seen in all languages/environments that use floating point numbers.

`double` should be able to store about twice as many digits as `float`, but all your floating point literals are `float` literals. Remove the `f` postfix on the `double` lines to actually use all the bits available for a `double`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I read in docs, that precision of float type is 6 and double is 15. But I did not understand what that means. Finally, I got the idea that precision means the maximum number of adjacent digits allowed. Everything that is outside is truncated or magically converted into other digits :) Thank you again.

Comment: The "magical conversion" happens because IEEE floating point numbers actually store binary digits (which get truncated). Converting binary numbers to decimal isn't always precise, so you get "strange numbers" instead of exactly cut-off numbers. In other words: if you look at the binary representation of your input and output you'll see that they are "cleanly truncated".

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that you're putting each of your numbers through 2 base conversions, and x2 and x4 also through a widening type conversion.

First of all you have decimal literals, which the compiler converts to binary fractions of type `float`, which have a precision of 23 binary digits (equivalent to about 7.2 decimal digits) and cannot accurately represent most decimal fractions, even those that fit into their precision. Then x2 and x4 are assigned to `double` variables, but since everything that does not fit into 23 binary digits has already been cropped, they don't magically regain the precision that was present in the literals.

Then, you convert the binary fractions back to decimal via `printf`, and get the previously mention ca. 7.2 decimal digits correct, and everything after that reflects the representational rounding error created by the base conversion.

It's basically the same as if you try to convert 1/3 to a decimal fraction 0.333 and back to a proper fraction 333/1000 - hey, why isn't it 1/3?

Read [the floating-point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de) for more information.

Comment: Besides, what are the solutions for money format (12.23$, 145789.45) where rounding errors are unacceptable?

Comment: @4centimeter: for those you'd use fixed point numbers and not floating point numbers. In Java that'd be a `BigDecimal` for example, there are probably libraries to do the same in C. Alternatively you store monetary amounts in cents (or the smallest possible unit you need) and format them to work correctly.

Comment: @Michael: strictly speaking yes. But by "floating point" I usually mean the IEEE floating point formats. Base-2 is just one problem. The other is the limited precision. `BigDecimal` is a Base-10, arbitrary precision floating point system. Those two fact **together** make it better suited for monetary values.

Comment: @Michael: still, for monetary values a fixed-point format (even one with implied scale) is the best solutions, as you'll always want **full** precision (in the sense that every value is well-defined down to the smallest unit).